# убрать валидацию yii2

Tags: php, yii2

[image: как убрать валидацию, если дочерний раскрывающийся список пуст!]

[['title', 'user_name', 'parentCatID', 'subCatID', 'category_id'],  'required'],

Comment: как убрать валидацию, если дочерний раскрывающийся список пуст

Comment: Убрать его из массива правил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        ['category_id', 'required', 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
    return $('#board-category_id').find('option').length > 1;
}"]
```

вот это для меня сработал

Comment: костыли наше всё, чем не устроил вариант `[['title', 'user_name', 'parentCatID', 'subCatID'], 'required'],`?

Comment: Типа еще клиентская валидация нужна.